# Quickest way to display a List<String> in a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm fairly new to Visual C# and I'm trying to create a `List<String>` whose contents are shown by a form widget, preferably using the form editor. Coming from a Qt/C++ background I usually do something like this:

- Create a custom data structure in my Model that wraps around a `QList<string>` and derives from the `Subject` class in the Observer pattern.
- Create a new widget that subclasses from `Observer` (which again is part of the Observer pattern) and one of Qt's list widgets. This newly created widget should be able to update the list when it receives a notification from the data structure.
- Make sure that the widget subscribes to the data structure at runtime.

This procedure is a pain in the butt and I'm sure that there's a better way, but I'm not here for Qt help right now. What's the quickest way to display the contents of a `List<String>` (or similar structure) in C#? I'm using WinForms.

Comment: `ListBox` with a `DataSource`. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// simple one-way, one-time binding 
var myItems = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
listBox1.DataSource = myItems;
```

```
// rebinding
var myItems = new List<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
listBox1.DataSource = myItems;
....
myItems.Add("ccc");
listBox1.DataSource = myItems;
```

```
// one-way, multi-time binding
var myItems = new BindingList<string> { "aaa", "bbb" };
listBox1.DataSource = myItems;
...
myItems.Add("ccc");
```

Comment: Why aren't items that were added after setting the `DataSource` shown? [(Context here.)](http://pastebin.com/N2haf0A3)

Comment: The simple binding is one-way, one-time. Use a BindingList or simply reset the DataSource after changing the collection.